# On Text Input Change Echo to Closest H3

Tags: jquery

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JF7PD/6/

```
<div class='group'>
    <h3>
        <span style="z-index:99999;position:absolute;margin-left:418px;top:0px"><a href="#" class="removeclass"><span class="ui-iconred ui-icon-circle-close"></span></a></span>
        <a href='#'><span id="accordionheadder">Column 1</span></a>
    </h3>
    <div>
        <div class='group'>
            <div class="boo">
                <span id="CoulmTitle">Column 1</span><br/>
                <div class="row">
                    <input type="text" name="mytext[]" id="Title_1" value="Column Title"></input>
                    <label for="username">Please enter the title for the data under this column</label>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <input type="text" name="mytext[]" id="ColumWidth_1" value="Column Width (px)"></input>
                    <label for="username">Please enter initial (page load) width for this column</label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="dropdown">
                    <select id="ColumInputType_1" name="age">
                        <option>
                            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Column Input Type
                        </option>
                        <option>
                            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Simple Text Input
                        </option>
                        <option>
                            &nbsp;&nbsp;Descriptive Text Input
                        </option>
                        <option> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Check/Tick</option>
                        <option>
                            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Progress Bar
                        </option>
                        <option>
                            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Date Picker
                        </option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've got a couple of these on my page and upon something being typed in `<input type="text" name="mytext[]" id="field_1" value="Column Title"></input>` I would like this to be echoed as the new column title.

The reason for this is due to it being sortable, so if the accordion is clasped then the person knows which one is which to be able to sort in the correct order without needing to open to know which one is which.

Best Regards,
Tim

Comment: Duplicate IDs in your code. That is invalid.

Comment: Just noticed, thanks @shaunakde, its now been edited

Comment: NO, the main problem lies in the text you are appending. It also has duplicated ID's, why dont you add a common class to `Column Title` fields.

Comment: I've just removed the duplicate ID's

Comment: `$(InputsWrapper).append(...)` still appends duplicate IDs, Use a counter

Comment: Please ignore the adding additional feature, I'm just wanting to know how to do it for one then I'll be going through my code to sort out the ID's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JF7PD/9/)

```
$(document).on('keyup', 'input[id^="ColumnTitle"]', function () {
    var value = this.value.length > 0 ? true : false;
    if (value) {
        $(this).closest('[role="tabpanel"]').prev().find('#accordionheadder').text(this.value);
        $(this).parents('.boo').find('[id^="CoulmTitle"]').text(this.value);
    }

});
```

Comment: The is perfect, can you please modify so if nothing is entered after click and then click of 'Column X' comes back?

Comment: How does ".find('#CoulmTitle')" work when it is "#CoulmTitle_X"? Works brilliantly :)

Comment: Just change it to `.find('[id^="CoulmTitle"]')`, it find elements - ID starting with `CoulmTitle`. Updated the code

Comment: I thought as much. Thank you very much for your help and pointing out my duplicate input ID's! :) +1